# asyncio run two different functions periodically with different intervals

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

Would it be possible using asyncio to run 2 different functions periodically with different interval for each function `f` forever?

If yes - could you please provide code example.

```
import asyncio

async def f1(host,*arg):
    # call every 1 sec
    pass

async def f2(url,*args):
    # call every 2 sec
    pass
```

Expected output:

```
00:00 f1 for 1.1.1.1

00:01 f1 for 1.1.1.1

00:02 f2 for 'google.com'

00:02 f1 for 1.1.1.1

00:03 f1 for 1.1.1.1

00:04 f2 for 'google.com'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Would it be possible using asyncio to run 2 different functions periodically with different interval for each f forever ?

Sure, just create a coroutine that does it in the "obvious" way, by awaiting the coroutine in an infinite loop with `asyncio.sleep()` between invocations:

```
import asyncio, time

async def invoke_forever(period, corofn, *args):
    while True:
        then = time.time()
        await corofn(*args)
        elapsed = time.time() - then
        await asyncio.sleep(period - elapsed)
```

Scenario described in the question would be set up with something like:

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.create_task(invoke_forever(1, f1, 'host1'))
loop.create_task(invoke_forever(2, f2, 'host2'))
loop.run_forever()
```

You can also use `asyncio.gather` to combine the two `invoke_forever` into one awaitable, which allows using the `asyncio.run` function introduced in Python 3.7:

```
async def invoke_both():
    await asyncio.gather(invoke_forever(1, f1, 'host1'),
                         invoke_forever(2, f2, 'host2'))

asyncio.run(invoke_both())
```

Comment: Hat's off !!! - works like a charm. Indeed i tried in the meantime using ensure_future combined with gather adding while loop in each f1,f2..but i like your solution more..(did not came to the point to add worker in the middle like you did. I am on 3.6, so i did not tried "run" method....Thank You !!!

Comment: Is there a way to include "timeout" for each task?. I tired asyncio.wait_for. I can't make it working in such a scenarios (above) as it stops all tasks after given timeout value.

Comment: @uneven Have you tried replacing `await corofn(*args)` with `await asyncio.wait_for( corofn(*args))`, perhaps with a try/except TimeoutError if you want to continue after a timeout?

Comment: Simple and efficient - You made my day/weekend Sir  - Thanks a million !!!

Comment: I'm getting the error "This event loop is already running"